# what are the matters of different positions of if-else in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote this to sort the prime numbers below 30.

```
p=[2]
i=2
while i<30:
    for x in p:
        if i%x==0:
            break
        else:
            p.append(i)
    i=i+1
print p
```

It gives me a long and duplicated result:

[image: duplicated result]

I noticed if I delete a tab in front of the 7th and 8th line then the code works fine. Why is that? Shouldn't 'if' and 'else' be in the same level?

Comment: the problem seams to be that you only want to append if there is no remainder-less division for any element of p, not all the elements of p, for which the remainder is non-zero.

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) shows an example just like this.